# Max Query Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

I have table "content":

```
content_id , relative_sortorder
1          1
2          1
3          2
4          3
**5          4**
6          1
7          2
8          ...
9          100
```

I want to do a query that returns the previous content_id by selecting the max(relative_sortorder) and that needs to be lower than the current relative_sortorder.

I don't have any idea, please help :)

This return only the max -

SELECT  max(c.relative_sortorder)
FROM   "DBA"."CONTENT" c
WHERE  c.relative_sortorder < 4 and content_id < 5

But I need the previous row
[image]

Alright, so i have these results, I want to filter them to show only the one with the maximum relative_sortorder, in this case second row. I dont know how to create the subquery

Comment: You should edit your question with desired results and any queries that you have tried.

Comment: As a side note, if your ids are auto-generated you shouldn't be doing things like `content_id < 5` - the value and relative order is meaningless.  Actually, that's true of all surrogate ids.  What happens when the row is corrected with non-key data that should change the "less" relationship?  As a side note, your expected results and sample data doesn't seem to match - please make sure they're related.

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right try t use `TOP n` functionality.

```
SELECT TOP 1 content_id
  FROM "DBA"."CONTENT" 
  WHERE relative_sortorder < 4
  ORDER BY relative_sortorder DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

use this query , hope that will be work for you .

```
 select content_id from content  
   where  content_id < current_content_id 
     and relative_sortorder = (select max(current_sortorder) 
       as maxorder from content where maxorder <  current_relative_sortorder )
```